# Mac and Linux giving Different Output for Apache Spark Window Function

Tags: apache-spark

I am doing a window operation on two columns with condition , whichever quantity is less (sku , sum(inward)) in that window will be be updated as column value.

Code Snippet

```
def getAgeing(win: WindowSpec) = {
            val getTotalOk = sum(col(inward)).over(win)
            when(col(sku) >= getTotalOk, getTotalOk).otherwise(col(sku))
          }
```

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window, WindowSpec}
def abc(inputDf : DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
          val partitionCols = col("no")
          val orderCol = "date"
          val ageingCols = "available_quantity_vds-and_okquan".split("_vds-and_")
          val ageingColsNew = ageingCols.map("new_" + _)
          val (sku, inward) = (ageingColsNew(0), ageingColsNew(1))
          val buckets = "5-8_vds-and_0-4_vds-and_9-12_vds-and_13-*".split("_vds-and_")
          val colName = "5-8_vds-and_0-4_vds-and_9-12_vds-and_13-*".split("_vds-and_")

          val inputDf1 = ageingCols.foldLeft(inputDf) { (df, c) =>
            df.withColumn("new_" + c, col(c))
          }.na.fill(0, ageingColsNew)

          def days(d: Long) = d * 86400

          def getWindowSpec(day: Long)  = {

            day match {
              case Long.MaxValue => Window.partitionBy(partitionCols).orderBy(col(orderCol).cast("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-(Long.MaxValue), 0)

              case _ => Window.partitionBy(partitionCols).orderBy(col(orderCol).cast("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-days(day - 1), 0)
            }
          }

          def getAgeing(win: WindowSpec) = {
            val getTotalOk = sum(col(inward)).over(win)

            when(col(sku) >= getTotalOk, getTotalOk).otherwise(col(sku))
          }

          val finDf = buckets.zip(colName).foldLeft(inputDf1) { (df, bucketAndCol) =>

            val (bucket, colName) = (bucketAndCol._1, bucketAndCol._2)
            val b = bucket.split("-").map(x => if (x == "*") Long.MaxValue else x.toLong)
            val win1 = getWindowSpec(b(1))

            if (b(0) > 1) {
              println("for output column : " + colName," Case > 1 : " + bucket ,
                "from time window : " + days(b(0) - 1) + " seconds" ,
                "to time window : " + days(b(1)) + " seconds")

              val win2 = getWindowSpec(b(0) - 1)
              df.withColumn(colName, getAgeing(win1) - getAgeing(win2))

            }
            else {
              println("for output column : " + colName,
                "Case < = 1 : " + bucket , "time window : " + days(b(1)) + " " +
                "seconds")
              df.withColumn(colName, getAgeing(win1))
            }
          }
          finDf.drop(ageingColsNew: _*)
}
```

Mac Output

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---+---+----+--------+
|            date|         no|                         available_quantity|                   okquan|0-4|5-8|9-12|    13-*|
+----------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---+---+----+--------+
|      2019-08-10| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      44045|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 44045.0|
|      2019-08-11| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      42333|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 42333.0|
|      2019-08-12| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      40202|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 40202.0|
|      2019-08-13| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      38253|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 38253.0|
|      2019-08-14| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      36799|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 36799.0|
|      2019-08-15| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      35501|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 35501.0|
|      2019-08-16| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      33368|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 33368.0|
|      2019-08-17| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      30899|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 30899.0|
|      2019-08-18| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      27477|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 27477.0|
|      2019-08-19| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      24084|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 24084.0|
|      2019-08-20| HEAVY_FLOW|                                      19813|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0| 19813.0|
|      2019-08-27| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     151736|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|151736.0|
|      2019-08-28| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     147874|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|147874.0|
|      2019-08-29| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     143551|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|143551.0|
|      2019-08-30| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     140001|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|140001.0|
|      2019-08-31| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     136876|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|136876.0|
|      2019-09-01| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     134522|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|134522.0|
|      2019-09-02| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     131716|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|131716.0|
|      2019-09-03| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     129199|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|129199.0|
|      2019-09-04| HEAVY_FLOW|                                     127420|                     null|0.0|0.0| 0.0|127420.0|
```

On Spark Notebook

```
+----------+-----------+------------------+------+--------+---+----+----+
|      date|         no|available_quantity|okquan|     0-4|5-8|9-12|13-*|
+----------+-----------+------------------+------+--------+---+----+----+
|2019-08-11| HEAVY_FLOW|             44045|  null| 44045.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-12| HEAVY_FLOW|             42333|  null| 42333.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-13| HEAVY_FLOW|             40202|  null| 40202.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-14| HEAVY_FLOW|             38253|  null| 38253.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-15| HEAVY_FLOW|             36799|  null| 36799.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-16| HEAVY_FLOW|             35501|  null| 35501.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-17| HEAVY_FLOW|             33368|  null| 33368.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-18| HEAVY_FLOW|             30899|  null| 30899.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-19| HEAVY_FLOW|             27477|  null| 27477.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-20| HEAVY_FLOW|             24084|  null| 24084.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-21| HEAVY_FLOW|             19813|  null| 19813.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-27| HEAVY_FLOW|            154791|  null|154791.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-28| HEAVY_FLOW|            151736|  null|151736.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-29| HEAVY_FLOW|            147874|  null|147874.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-30| HEAVY_FLOW|            143551|  null|143551.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-08-31| HEAVY_FLOW|            140001|  null|140001.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-01| HEAVY_FLOW|            136876|  null|136876.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-02| HEAVY_FLOW|            134522|  null|134522.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-03| HEAVY_FLOW|            131716|  null|131716.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-04| HEAVY_FLOW|            129199|  null|129199.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-05| HEAVY_FLOW|            127420|  null|127420.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-06| HEAVY_FLOW|            121866|  null|121866.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-07| HEAVY_FLOW|            118942|  null|118942.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2019-09-08| HEAVY_FLOW|            115714|  null|115714.0|0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
```

time buckets are created with "5-8_vds-and_0-4_vds-and_9-12_vds-and_13-*"

```
(for output column : 0-4,Case < = 1 : 0-4,time window : 345600 seconds)
(for output column : 5-8, Case > 1 : 5-8,from time window : 345600 seconds,to time window : 691200 seconds)
(for output column : 9-12, Case > 1 : 9-12,from time window : 691200 seconds,to time window : 1036800 seconds)
(for output column : 13-*, Case > 1 : 13-*,from time window : 1036800 seconds,to time window : -86400 seconds)
```

why Mac and Linux machine are giving me different output.

i am doing calculation like for a window of 11 to 20 days.

i am creating 2 window of 0-20 and 0-10 and then subtracting from

`output = Ageing(0-20) - Ageing(10-20)`

"spark version - 2.0.0"

Comment: could you please check current time of both of the system. May be timezone related issue.

Comment: issue was for some reason  `okquan` have different datatype in both machine. on Mac it was `double` , On Linux it was `string` so `fill.na(0)` will fill `null` for string columns. leading to this issue